# What happens on a DC-DC grid connection after a perturbation in the synchronous grid?

Tags: frequency, generator, power-engineering, stability, power-grid

Consider the Continental Europe synchronous grid. This power system has some DC-DC connections with other countries (for example one with Great-Britain). Suppose now there is a sudden big outage causing the loss of 1-2 GW of generation in Continental Europe grid. This outage leads to a frequency transient. Since Great Britain is connected to the CE grid throug DC-DC links, I imagine that the power transferring on that link would not change during this transient because the two grids are not synchronized, but it seems strange that there is no perturbation on this link even if there is such big outage.

Would the power transfer change? Is there any perturbation on this link?

Comment: Depends on how you set up the control system to respond. There is no given answer to this but one which will be considered and calculated for during the engineering phase of the link.

Comment: As @winny says. The interconnectors may be programmed to mimic rotary machines and increase power during a frequency transient : that programming probably changes according to the UK grid's status (excess capacity) at the time.

Comment: The DC grid  will experience a DC transient but the dependency on many sources determines the net  response.

Comment: thank you very much to all of you! It's clear!

Answer (score 0):

A few GW loss of AC grid capability will only cause a relatively small frequency deviation (not even 1 Hz). The DCDC converters don't care (electrically) if their input is 50 or 49 Hz. They do have shedding capability that can be triggered if the input frequency is not correct, but this is part of normal load management.